# Can someone explain to me why I get empty string as a result?

Tags: python-3.x

What im trying to do is get the longest substring in s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order.

For some reason alphasub has no string in it at the end and I don't know why

```
start = 0
sub = 1
maxsub = 0
current = 0
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
leng = len(s)
for i in range(leng):
    if i != leng - 1:
        if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
            current = i
            sub = 1
            while current < (leng-1):
                if s[current] <=s [current+1]:
                    sub += 1
                    current += 1
                else:
                    break
                if(sub>maxsub):
                    maxsub = sub
                    start = i

alphasub = s[start:maxsub]

print("longest substring is: " + alphasub)
```

Comment: Time to use a debugger then. Also your code looks overly complicated, at the very least the line `if i!=leng-1:` is unnecessary, you could just have the range go to `leng - 1` instead

Comment: I did used the debugger and did the math in my head... forgot to write in code s[start:start+maxsub]. Thanks for the help.

Comment: probably want `alphasub=[start:start+maxsub]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String slicing takes starting and end position. 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Change alphasub=s[start:maxsub] to alphasub=s[start:start+maxsub]. You should see the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use `print`'s to check your code.
I've added some prints at the end of your code like so:

```
print(s)
print(start)
print(maxsub)
alphasub=s[start:maxsub]

print ("longest substring is: " + alphasub)
```

Which outputs:

```
azcbobobegghakl
7
5
longest substring is:
```

It is starting at 7, and ending at 5, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I used debugger, saw that the values of start and maxsub are 7 and 5 and I did the math in my head to add them but forgot to write it in the code... Time for some break. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is because `maxsub` is the longest substring. But that isn't the position of the end. The substring starts at `start`, so you will need to use `alphasub=s[start:maxsub+start]`. You can figure this out by using lots or `print`'s

Comment: Ah, we wrote at the same time, but yeah you figured it out. Feel free to up my answer ;) (gotta get dem unlocks)